# The parameter is incorrect while using sns.pairplot()

Tags: python, seaborn

So I currently have a dataset that is 122X30 named df.

The data is such:

| PAT_ID | PAT_SEX | PAT_AGE | PAT_DOB | ptt | Date of death/transplant/last f/u | Dead/LVAD/transplant(1)/alive(0) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ******* | 0 | 62 | 5/31/1954 | 38.0 | 8/8/2016 |  |

I've just given the first 7 features of the first row to hide confidential information but I believe that's enough to get a general idea of he dataset.

After reading it in like so:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

I wanted to get a general idea of what the relationship of the features so I decided to use seaborn's pairplot like so:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.pairplot(df)
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, however, I get this:

[image]

I've tried changing matplotlib's backend to Augg and other bankends but to no avail.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: What IDE are you using in that case? What are your `matplotlib` and `seaborn` versions? Have you tried downgrading? What did you use to try switching the backend with (was it something like `import matplotlib as mpl <...> mpl.use('TkAgg')`? I've seen discussions like [this](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection/issues/7035), could be worth digging there, though you might have probably been there already.

Comment: I'm using VS code. My matplotlib version is 3.5.2 . I've looked more into the github issue you linked, let me try and downgrade my version and see how it goes.

Comment: Sorry for the slow update: Downgrading does change anything unfortunately. Still the same issue

Comment: Is the error the same when launching from a simple python prompt?

Comment: Running the python program without sns.pairplot allows the program to be executed normally. However, with sns.pairplot, the error shows up.

Comment: Running the code at python prompt, not in VS Code, results in the same issue. The dataset is confidential (patient data) but I'll try adding the non-confidential parts of it.

Comment: Just want to ask if you double checked that your string data isnt throwing the error?

Comment: Try switching Backend to Agg maybe more of a memory issue or revert back to Tkinter 3.3.3

Comment: @JasonChia I've dropped every column with even one null value. I've also ensured that every value in the dataset is numerical. But still, same error.

Comment: @Noah reverting to Agg causes the program to run infinity. Like after 1 hour or so the program would be still running with no output whatsoever.

Comment: Have you tried simply running your code with a simple Data Frame (Simply Generate the one you gave as example above and multiply the rows so you get more data). When I try with my system this works fine. Would be interesting to see if static data works. If so your gone have to provide mor info about your data. Atleast the datatypes of the columns

Comment: @Noah I made a new dataset with just the first 4 features and it seems to run fine. I'm guessing there is a column breaking program

Comment: Dates, dates, dates, dates. Uggggggggg it's the dates that are breaking sns.pairplot

Comment: @JosephAttia Need assistance on solving your dates issues? Kinda was thinking about the dates when commenting about string formatting.